# Insert spinner on function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spinner, sql-insert

Insert spinner on function JavaScript.

Hi everyone, I'm taking my first steps with JavaScript and I find myself unable to insert a spinner
I wrote the following code, could you help me understand the problem?

```js
document.getElementById('insert').addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");                                                        
    spinner.style.display = "";                                                          
    insertDataToDatabase(results.data);                                                          
    spinner.style.display = "none";                                                         
     }, false);

    function insertDataToDatabase(data) {
        
    data_noheader = data.slice(1);
        
        for(i=0;i<data_noheader.length;i++){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'import',
                    data: data_noheader[i]
                    },
                    success: function(response) {

                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                    },
            });
        }
    }`
```

I was trying to activate the spinner at index 0 of the loop and deactivate the spinner at the completion of the insertDataToDatabase function.

Comment: Just to clarify, by _spinner_, you're referring to some sort of spinning indicator, to inform the user that stuff's happening. You'd like this spinner to continue until you get a confirmation that the data's been entered into the databse?

You could also improve your question by stating in what way it's _not working_. That may help get you more precise answers

Comment: Your AJAX call is asynchronous, which means it will still be running while your code hides the spinner again.  You need to hide it in the success callback.  Search for eg "*ajax spinner*" and you'll find many examples here.

Comment: is that `}` ` just a copy paste error or an actual syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this with `Promises` or `async/await`.

Here are the example:

```js
document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener(
  "click",
  async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
    spinner.style.display = "";
    await insertDataToDatabase(results.data);
    spinner.style.display = "none";
  },
  false
);

async function insertDataToDatabase(data) {
  data_noheader = data.slice(1);

  for (i = 0; i < data_noheader.length; i++) {
    await $.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        action: "import",
        data: data_noheader[i],
      },
      success: function (response) {},
      error: function (response) {},
    });
  }
}
```

Or even a bit better solution:

```js
document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener(
  "click",
  async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
    spinner.style.display = "";
    await insertDataToDatabase(results.data);
    spinner.style.display = "none";
  },
  false
);

async function insertDataToDatabase(data) {
  data_noheader = data.slice(1);

  await Promise.all(data_noheader.map((row) => {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        action: "import",
        data: row,
      },
      success: function (response) {},
      error: function (response) {},
    });
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
using the second option with Promise the spinner activates but does not deactivate (Uncaught (in promise) Object)

Comment: Oh, looks like there are some error there. Could you share more info, please?